Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2024
Summary: Proof Assistants Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for a special election on April 9th, 2024 to bring in 2 more moderators.
For full details of the process, see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange. The timeline:

Starting on April 9th, 2024, users can nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the discussion and election tags.)

On April 16th, 2024, if there are 3 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 3 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination.)

If there are still fewer than 3 candidates at the end of the nomination period even after it is extended, the election will be considered a failure, and the site will be shut down.


If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on April 24th, 2024 or May 1st, 2024, if we need to extend the nomination period.


If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.

"If there are still fewer than 3 candidates at the end of the nomination period even after it is extended, the election will be considered a failure"
I assume this was either a typo, or we avoided this scenario by removing a nomination?

@Eric For pro-tempore elections, if they get past the extended nomination phase and there are still not enough candidates to be competitive, we appoint those who are nominated.
